# Can you pull an API call straight into a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, dataframe

I am building a small program to chart some API data. I have set it up to pull the data and then create a local json which I then create a dataframe from.

Is there a way to skip the local file and pull the data straight into the dataframe?

As you can see the example I am working with is Ireland, but I would like to end up with something that can reference any country, and would hope to avoid creating a file.

```
# Import the libraries
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

# Save the current API call as a JSON file
# countryStatusdDayOne

# 1. Make an API call and store the response.
url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/total/dayone/country/ireland'
data = requests.get(url)

# Store the API response in a variable.
available_data = data.json()

filename = 'data/covid_call__ireland_day_one_workable.json'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(available_data, f, indent=4)

# read the json
ireland = pd.read_json('data/covid_call__ireland_day_one_workable.json')

# create a dataframe 
df_ire = pd.DataFrame(ireland)
```

This is all very new to me so any advice on how to format or improve my code is also very welcome!

Comment: I don't think there's a way to patch an API call directly to Pandas. The only way would be do a get request on API, and pass the json to `pd.read_json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `json_normalize`:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize


url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/total/dayone/country/ireland'
data = requests.get(url)

# Store the API response in a variable.
available_data = data.json()
df = json_normalize(available_data)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: That seemed to work but I got this error code back:

C:\Users\Cormac\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:11: FutureWarning: pandas.io.json.json_normalize is deprecated, use pandas.json_normalize instead
  # This is added back by InteractiveShellApp.init_path()

What should I do to avoid this not working in future?

Comment: @CormacDaly this is just a warning and not an error, if you are using  ```pandas v1.0.1``` which is the latest version, then you can import it that way ```from pandas import json_normalize``` that should remove that warning

Comment: Thank you. I have implemented your suggestion and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use the `pd.json_normalize` to read your data from memory, and skip creating a file on disk.

if you're reading multiple countries, you can hold all the values inside a dictionary.

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

# Save the current API call as a JSON file
# countryStatusdDayOne

country = 'ireland'

# 1. Make an API call and store the response.
url = f'https://api.covid19api.com/total/dayone/country/{country}'
data = requests.get(url)

# Store the API response in a variable.
available_data = data.json()

dfs = {}

dfs[f'{country}'] = pd.json_normalize(available_data)
```

---

```
print(dfs['ireland'])

    Country CountryCode Province City CityCode Lat Lon  Confirmed  Deaths  \
0   Ireland                                      0   0          1       0   
1   Ireland                                      0   0          1       0   
2   Ireland                                      0   0          1       0   
3   Ireland                                      0   0          2       0   
4   Ireland                                      0   0          6       0   
..      ...         ...      ...  ...      ...  ..  ..        ...     ...   
62  Ireland                                      0   0      20833    1265   
63  Ireland                                      0   0      21176    1286   
64  Ireland                                      0   0      21506    1303   
65  Ireland                                      0   0      21772    1319   
66  Ireland                                      0   0      21983    1339   

    Recovered  Active                  Date  
0           0       1  2020-02-29T00:00:00Z  
1           0       1  2020-03-01T00:00:00Z  
2           0       1  2020-03-02T00:00:00Z  
3           0       2  2020-03-03T00:00:00Z  
4           0       6  2020-03-04T00:00:00Z  
..        ...     ...                   ...  
62      13386    6182  2020-05-01T00:00:00Z  
63      13386    6504  2020-05-02T00:00:00Z  
64      13386    6817  2020-05-03T00:00:00Z  
65      13386    7067  2020-05-04T00:00:00Z  
66      13386    7258  2020-05-05T00:00:00Z
```